# Mediaplayer and delay in playing

Tags: android, media-player, media, handler

I create small application which is media player. I have method where I have a song. I want to delay playing sound after I clicked a button. How I can do this delay. I want to click on the button and after 5 seconds music is playing. I am using: `MediaPlayer.create` to get song and `mediaplayer.start()` to start playing, but I don;t know how I can delay start playing my song.

Comment: you want the delay or delay exists and you want to eliminate it?

Comment: I want to run activity, click on the button and after 5 seconds, music will be playing.

Comment: i had past code for you , try that it is work fine..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a Handler in your Activity to delay events such as starting the mediaplayer in your case:

```
private RefreshHandler mRedrawHandler = new RefreshHandler(); 
 private RefreshHandler mRedrawHandler = new RefreshHandler(); 

     class RefreshHandler extends Handler {  
            @Override  
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {  
             MyActivity.startMusic();  
            }  

            public void sleep(long delayMillis) {  
              this.removeMessages(0);  
              sendMessageDelayed(obtainMessage(0), delayMillis);  
            }  
          };
```

In onClick of button, call `mRedrawHandler.sleep(5000);` , `startMusic()` is a method where you are starting the mucsic playback.

Answer (score 2):

In onClickListener of the button run a thread to delay for 5 seconds. Then call mediaplayer.start() after the delay.

Answer (score 1):

for Delay video we have SeekTo method,,try this it work fine.

```
                     final int playbackTime=5*1000;

                        System.out.println("Play Back Time====="+playbackTime);

                      getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT); 


                          Uri video = Uri.parse(videourl);                 
                          videoView.setVideoURI(video);
                          videoView.requestFocus();
                          videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() 
                          {

                              public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) 
                              {                      

                                  videoView.start();
                                  videoView.seekTo(playbackTime);

                              }
                          });
```