# How to add an delay before starting playback in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

This maybe an odd question, but I want to add an artificial delay (say, 100ms) before starting an audio playback using MediaPlayer class in Android. This should happen after the AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_REQUEST_GRANTED and before player.start(). Here's my code:

```
 int result = am.requestAudioFocus(afChangeListener, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN_TRANSIENT);
 if (result == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_REQUEST_GRANTED){
               //add delay
               player.start();}
```

Tried Googled this but can't seem to find anything useful and I'm too new to even know what to search for.. would appreciate any pointers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Handler to add delay

```
int result = am.requestAudioFocus(afChangeListener, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN_TRANSIENT);
if (result == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_REQUEST_GRANTED){
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            player.start();
        }
    }, 100);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this would help but I found this while browsing earlier I hope this helps.
[Mediaplayer and delay in playing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9884515/mediaplayer-and-delay-in-playing)

Comment: it does thanks, but SiSa's solution is more applicable