# How to play audio with MediaPlayer without delayed?

Tags: android

I want to play an mp3 audio file with MediaPlayer, when I call start() method it takes a few seconds ( 1 or 2 seconds) before the audio file is played.

Now I want it play immediately when I click the "start" button.
please help.

here is my code :

```
MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer();
player.setDataSource(path);
player.prepare();
player.seekTo(_start_at);
player.start();
```

and the logcat :

> V/MediaPlayer: message received msg=8, ext1=0, ext2=0
>
> V/MediaPlayer: notify(8, 0, 0) callback on disconnected mediaplayer
>
> V/MediaPlayer-JNI: setDataSourceFD: fd 57
>
> V/MediaPlayer: setDataSource(57, 0, 576460752303423487)
>
> V/MediaPlayer: message received msg=8, ext1=0, ext2=0
>
> V/MediaPlayer: notify(8, 0, 0) callback on disconnected mediaplayer
>
> V/MediaPlayer: setVideoSurfaceTexture
>
> V/MediaPlayer: prepare
>
> V/MediaPlayer: message received msg=200, ext1=973, ext2=0
>
> W/MediaPlayer: info/warning (973, 0)
>
> V/MediaPlayer: callback application
>
> V/MediaPlayer: back from callback
>
> V/MediaPlayer: message received msg=5, ext1=0, ext2=0
>
> V/MediaPlayer: New video size 0 x 0
>
> V/MediaPlayer: callback application
>
> V/MediaPlayer: back from callback
>
> V/MediaPlayer: message received msg=1, ext1=0, ext2=0
>
> V/MediaPlayer: prepared
>
> V/MediaPlayer: signal application thread
>
> V/MediaPlayer: callback application
>
> V/MediaPlayer: back from callback
>
> V/MediaPlayer: prepare complete - status=0
>
> I/MediaPlayer: Don't send intent. msg.arg1 = 0, msg.arg2 = 0
>
> E/MediaPlayer: Should have subtitle controller already set
>
> V/MediaPlayer-JNI: start
>
> V/MediaPlayer: start
>
> V/MediaPlayer: message received msg=300, ext1=0, ext2=0
>
> V/MediaPlayer: Received SEC_MM_PLAYER_CONTEXT_AWARE
>
> V/MediaPlayer: callback application
>
> V/MediaPlayer: back from callback
>
> V/MediaPlayer: message received msg=6, ext1=0, ext2=0
>
> V/MediaPlayer: Received MEDIA_STARTED
>
> V/MediaPlayer: callback application
>
> V/MediaPlayer: back from callback
>
> I/MediaPlayer: send context aware event
>
> I/MediaPlayer: sendBroadcast CONTEXT_AWARE_MUSIC_INFO - type(start) - id (1183)
>
> V/MediaPlayer-JNI: native_finalize
>
> V/MediaPlayer-JNI: release
>
> V/MediaPlayer: isPlaying: 1
>
> V/MediaPlayer-JNI: isPlaying: 1
>
> I/MediaPlayer: sendBroadcast CONTEXT_AWARE_MUSIC_INFO - type(stop) - id(1183)
>
> V/MediaPlayer-JNI: stop
>
> V/MediaPlayer: stop

Comment: Try to prepare the Player and the file before starting it

Comment: @tainguyen Why not you initialize the mediaplayer before button click. And only start on button click.

Comment: Alternatively SoundPool can be used to quickly play very short sounds files, like game sound effects etc.

Comment: @AhmadSattout tried to do that, but it did not work

Comment: run the media player when the activity is started, not on the create. try running media player on onStart() or onResume().

Comment: @Ranjit it not work

Comment: @sasikumar I start it when button is clicked

Comment: refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9884515/mediaplayer-and-delay-in-playing